# Make jQuery cloned object draggable on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been able to open a page and drag items onto the surface div tags onto the surface. I have also been able to move the items and resize them.

Now, I am trying to load the same objects onto the surface when the page loads and still have the capability to move them, resize or remove the cloned them

I was able to add the object to the page, however, when i move the objects they revert to the original position and i am unable to resize the cloned object.

Below is my code, can somebody please tell me where i may be going wrong with my implementation?

```
 $(document).ready(function (event, ui) {
    if ($('#rlvPdf_ctrl0_pnlPdfPage').length) {
      var clonedObject = $("#textbox").clone();
            clonedObject.addClass("dropped");

         //$(function () {
         //Make element draggable
         clonedObject.draggable({ revert: false});

         $("#rlvPdf_ctrl0_pnlPdfPage").droppable({
             accept: 'textbox',
             drop: function (event, ui) {
             $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
                    $("#rlvPdf_ctrl0_pnlPdfPage.clonedObject").addClass("dropped");
                }
        });
    clonedObject.appendTo("#rlvPdf_ctrl0_pnlPdfPage");
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="toolbar" class="toolbar">
     <div id="textbox" class="draggableItem">                
        <span class="draghandle">::</span>
        <span class="draggableItemContentText">Text Box</span>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="rlvPdf_ctrl0_pnlPdfPage" pageNum="1" >
```

**CSS**

```
     .dropped
    {
        position: absolute !important;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: wheat;
    }

    .draggableItem
    {
        position: relative;
        height: 18px;
        width: 150px;
        z-index: 1000;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px black;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is. But your code that you posted is broken. I've cleaned it up and created a http://jsfiddle.net/1tuy5hhp/,  in that example you can see the cloned item is draggable and can be dropped anywhere.

Comment: Changed my strategy on this but your input helped me.
Thanks